# Laravel : Add text area if the user checked a specific choice (radio)

Tags: laravel, if-statement, radio-button

I want to display textarea or text input if the user select a specific choice in form

I tried to use if but even the choice (radio) doesn't display

view :

```
@elseif($question->question_type === 'checkbox')
                  @foreach($question->option_name as $key=>$value)
                  @if($value === 'else')
                  <input type="checkbox" id="{{ $value }}" name="{{ $question->id }}[answer]" value="{{ $value}}"/>
                  <input type="text" name="{{ $question->id }}[answer]" placeholder="Votre commentaire"/>
                  <label for="{{$value}}">{{ $value }}</label>
                  @else
                  <p style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
                      <input type="checkbox" id="{{ $value }}" name="{{ $question->id }}[answer]" value="{{ $value}}"/>
                      <label for="{{$value}}">{{ $value }}</label>
                  </p> 
                  @endif                 
                  @endforeach
```

The question's choice is array ,the table :[image: The question table DATA]

The else choice doesn't display in the page

Comment: I tried this code  :
<div id="textboxes" style="display: none">
                          <input id="answer" type="text" name="{{ $question->id }}[answer]">
                        </div>
<script>
      $(function() {
        $('input[name="type"]').on('click', function() {
            if ($(this).val() == 'else') {
                $('#textboxes').show();
            }
            else {
                $('#textboxes').hide();
            }
        });
    });
  </script> 
but its not working

Comment: When should the textarea etc. appear - immediately after you select something in the form or after you POST it?

Comment: i found the issue the problem was i forget the name and value of input radio